# Is it possible to have google analytics users that can only view pages within a subdirectory?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, multisite

Have setup a WordPress multisite which is using the same GA tracking ID to make things much simpler in our Google Analytics Dashboard (plus there is like a limit of 50 individual IDs you can track with one account I think?).

WP multisite is setup on subdirectories and not subdomains, e.g.

- mysite.com.au/sitename1
- mysite.com.au/sitename2

Anyway, some of the admin from the sites want access to the Google Analytics for their site. Upon investigating, I found that they would be able to access stats for other sites (besides their own) within the multisite. We definitely do not want this.

Is there a way to limit a GA user account so that they can only view pages within their own site (a fixed subdirectory), for example:

- mysite.com.au/sitename1

and not be able to view information from any other site subdirectories? I'm a beginner to Google Analytics and I heard I might be able to setup particular views, goals or campaigns to achieve this.

Comment: I have tried creating a segment that filters pages on the subdirectory name but I can't get a GA user account to be restricted to just that segment. Apparently views might be more suitable? - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2649553?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Views (bad thing - each property can just have 25 Views)

You find Views in the right column of the Admin page. Add a new View through the Dropdown. You can now set a filter to this View (/sitename1).

[image]

After this click on "User Management" in the View column and give the User you want to have there access.

Comment: Cool. I followed through with this and setup a view with a filter. I also used segmentation on top (not sure if that is a good or bad thing yet). Still have to wait some time for data to show up. Would the 25 view limitation go away with an Analytics 360 account?

Comment: If you use 360 the Limit is much higher. It´s seems to be also possible to raise your Limit for a non-360 account to 200. Maybe this post can help you https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Account-Access/Views-per-property-Limit/td-p/486254#